# Method signature declared as throws Exception; implemented as throws a subclass of Exception

Tags: java, exception, implementation, method-signature

I have the following interface declaration:

```
public interface SomeInterface {

    void someMethod() throws Exception;

}
```

I use a third party to generate an implementation of this class (JavaCC - for the curious)

The generated class looks naively like this:

```
public class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {

   public void someMethod() throws SomeException {

    // Does something

   }
}
```

Where `SomeException` is of course a subclass of `Exception`.

(Not) surprisingly the code does not compile.

Does anyone have any input concerning this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

renamed the method `SomeMethod()` to `someMethod()`.

It had been a typo of mine... (sorry)

**EDIT #2:**

Sorry all - huge mistake of mine. Writing this example had forced me to strip down the code. I had not noticed that the mistake was elsewhere and not with the signature.

Thats the "magic" of runtime compile and custom class loading...

Comment: "any input?" is not a question with a definitive answer.

Comment: The code as posted will compile. Can you reproduce the problem with this sample code?

Comment: A Huge mistake of mine. Since I had to strip down the code for this example I did not notice that the problem had been elsewhere... Really Sorry for this!!!!

Comment: For the record: it is perfectly legal to have an overriding method in a subclass declare that it throws only a subclass of the exception, or even none at all.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't compile because the method names aren't the same (check the caps on S/someMethod)

Comment: But if you fix that, it should compile fine.

Comment: But this compiles:

import java.io.*;

interface SomeInterface {
 void someMethod() throws Exception;

}

class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {

   public void someMethod() throws IOException {

    // Does something

   }
}

So the problem must be something else...

Answer (score 1):

Case is important in Java. Your interface says `someMethod` and your class says `SomeMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

Why does your interface method throw Exception?  This is almost always wrong.  Exception is just the base type the rest extend from; it's not meant to be used this way.

Comment: Its because of class loading issues... The code that generates the class also generates the exception which will be loaded in a different class loader than the interface. I cannot, to my knowledge, have the interface use the same exception type since it will never be the same. Is that somewhat clearer now?

Comment: There's occasionally a reason to do this: it says that the method can throw an implementation-specific checked exception. For example consider a persistence mechanism that could either write to a database or a file. One throws SQLException, the other throws IOException. In either case, the application needs to catch the exception when a write fails, and take some action (ranging from simply wrapping in a RuntimeException/subclass to generating a customized error page/dialog).

Comment: What is wrong with interface method throwing? If implementation needs to throw, do you suggest throwing unchecked, which would be undocumented by the interface? This would seem totally wrong.

Comment: Checked exceptions themselves are already totally wrong. Just saying.

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods protection is public and the other is default, that's why your code does not compile. Make both public or default.